# Where could i found id for performance event of IBM Power8

Tags: performance, profiling

Where could i found ids for performance events of IBM Power8? I am using perf on power8 platform.

I found parts of it is listed in source code of perf and oprof. And I also found the events are grouped and listed in a document but without event id. So is there any official document for them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ophelp' from the oprofile package will display all of the events.  The operf utility (also part of the oprofile package) can use the listed event names directly.
If you need to use perf, and the 0x* event values directly, you can convert the event names to their values via individually passing them through ophelp.
i.e.

```
$ ophelp PM_ANY_THRD_RUN_CYC  | awk {'printf "%x\n",$N'}
100fa
```